# Route to Controller/Action isn't generated correctly in the html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view with an Html helper with the specified action and Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitReview", "Product"))
{
    <-- other html -->

     <a href="#">Cancel</a>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

`SubmitReview` action in the `ProductController.cs` looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitReview(ProductPageViewModel model)
{
    /* data processing and saving */
    return null; //For testing
}
```

Browser generated html for the form looks like this:

```
<form action="/.SubmitReview" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">  
    <-- other html -->
</form>
```

If I move the action to the controller with another existing Post method (ex. `LoginController`, then the action tag would be in a proper format and the breakpoint inside the `SubmitReview` will be hit:

```
<form action="site.axd/Login/SubmitReview" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"> 
    <-- other html -->
</form>
```

Why this can be happening when I try to add post method to the ProductController (it contains all the get method for parent views)?

Comment: This makes no sense, do you have any weird custom HTTP/IIS handlers or a custom `Html.BeginForm` method?

Comment: You will not get the `site.axd` prefix in the `action` attribte using `Html.BeginForm()` so there is something else going on that your have not told us

Comment: I've taken over a project, so might be smth I'm missing myself... Thanks for the tip, @DavidG, will check if there are any custom handlers somewhere